# How can I check a correct installation of the Net 4 Framework?

Tags: .net-4.0, failed-installation

One of our customers got the not so helpful 'Automation Error' when the VB6 code of our application tried to instantiate some Net classes through a Com visible wrapper. The problem went away when I reinstalled the Net 4 Framework on the computer. We are talking about a Win7 SP1 computer here on which the Net 4 Framework was installed prior to the installation of our application (the installer checks for the presence of the Net4 framework and installs it if absent).

Is there some tool, or log file on the client's computer that can help identify Net4 (Client profile) installation failures?